# Bootstrap datetimepicker CSS problems

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the [bootstrap datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) on a ASP.NET application. I'm getting some weird CSS problems though. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the icon is set far to the right, the background is blue, and there is a black box wherever the cursor is. These are the files I'm using on my webpages:

```
<link href="~/Content/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Chart.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
```

And this is what the html/js looks like where I use datetimepicker (the code is right from their website).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there an issue with the way I'm importing these files or maybe the CSS file?

Thanks!

Comment: please put the bootstrap related css at the last.

Comment: Moved it, no change

Answer (score 0):

Some css files seem to be conflicted, You can find out which css files affect the length of input box and mouse hover effect on datetimepicker.
Bootstrap version might affect those issues.